# Error while running on Mule Server 3.7.0 in AnypointStudio

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

Hi I am running my mule application on mule server 3.7.0 and its showing an error as : -

An internal error occurred during: "Launching pro_run".
java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.tooling.maven.ui.launch.MuleWithMavenLaunchDelegate.shouldRun(MuleWithMavenLaunchDelegate.java:52)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.launch(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

This is differnet from standard NulPointerException. This situation was arising while starting mule server 3.7.0. I have tried many ways to debug it but can't figure out why its there . Any suggestions or help would be great help .

Comment: this is not a duplicate question @Andy Turner

Comment: You've given us no information as to what you are trying to do, and no information about how you've tried to debug it. Without that information, it's just a plain old NPE question.